# AuthFailure while trying to connect android device to wampserver(localhost) using volley

Tags: android, android-volley

I am trying to connect my Android device to localhost ie wampserver
using android volley

**This is my code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      String url = "http://192.16x.x.xxx/folderName/ClutchTester.php";


      JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext()).add(request);
    }
}
```

Toast says **AuthFailureError**. the IP address I am using here is an IPv4 Address. Does anybody know why I am getting this error and how I can solve this?

Comment: What happenns if you call the url from a local browser isntead of your android device?

Comment: It's working fine when i call it from local browser

Comment: @Frank Can you please help me out with this??? I am in need of this very badly

Comment: how your device connected to your wamp server ?

Comment: I am trying to connect with wifi

Comment: run your url in your device browser and see if this site is reachable ?

Answer (score 0):

> Try to assign fixed ip to your pc instead of get automatically

When you are done

- Now your router know where to send those packets if get and At your pc your wampserver will handle rest.

Reason : The ip you are using is probably not found by your router since ip is automatically assigned.

Don't forget

- Change your url ip with the ip you have fixed for your pc in your code.